# read.xls() and arguments in R give read.table error "no lines available in input"

Tags: r, perl, character-encoding, read.table

I am having a hard time importing some data from `.xls` files in R.

```
library(gdata)

file.names <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.xls$")
file.names
for (file in seq(file.names))
    temp <- read.xls(file.names[file], 
                    verbose = FALSE, skip = 16, nrows = 14, header = FALSE,
                    check.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE, fileEncoding="UTF-8")
    write.csv(temp, "file.csv")
```

The code above fails to do what i want, producing the error i provided in the *title* *section* of this question. Some similar question here is SO aren't helpful at all.

Is there a conflict with additional arguments? Could this be a `perl` script error or something caused by bad encoding?

Comment: You will need to provide a reproducible example by posting the input. (Note that there is an error in the code posted, likely unrelated to your problem -- only the `read.xls` statement will be repeatedly executed by the `for` and then only the last file read will be written out.)

Comment: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94QvTfp4BUndXo4Z29qUVFJLW8/edit?usp=sharing) is a file similar to mine where you can exploit to reproduce your example

Comment: taking advantage of your feedback, how can i `append` instead of just overwrite?

Comment: Maybe i am making me look really stupid. But how is this `Perl`?

Comment: `gdata` uses this `xls2csv.pl` script file in order to read `.xls` files.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck It's not robust though. Any additional argument produces errors, besides that crappy encoding. `48` columns but some of them should be dropped as `NULL`. what's next?

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `sep=` and `fileEncoding=` arguments in which case I get a 14x48 data frame with the sample data.